# ASP.NET Web API: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: asp.net-web-api, server, cors, localhost

I'm trying to get my client (on localhost) to successfully call my server (also running local) with no luck. I've tried just about every solution I can find online with no luck, Postman calls to the server are successful, and similar front end calls to other published services are successful. Hoping for a miracle/help from a stranger!

So my current set up is as follows:

In Global.asax I have -

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

    }

    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            Response.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

In WebApi.Config -

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        AddRoutes(config);
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:4201", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
    }
```

with System.Web.Http.Cors imported...

and in Web.Config I have -

```
 <system.webServer>
 <handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
```

</system.webServer>

Note I've tried on both Safari and Chrome (along with Chrome's CORS extension).
I'm getting all of these errors, but given my other testing, I'm thinking it is in fact the CORS issue...

[image]

Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In case someone finds this helpful... after trying what I thought was everything, I added the following to Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
            Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
            Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            Response.Flush();
            
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure if this has to be combined with everything else I posted in my question, but right now I'm too elated to go through process of elimination. Good luck